# SQL group by two fields counts for both fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some MySQL code like this:

```
select 
Country, 
if(upper(District) like 'A%', 'A',
if(upper(District) like '%B', 'B','C')) as Field1Type,
count(*) as Salescount
FROM tablename
group by Country, District;
```

which returns data like this:

```
Country District Salescount
--------------------------- 
France   A          10      
France   B          20              
France   C          45          
Germany  A          30          
Germany  B          5           
Germany  C          50
```

How can I also get the totals per country, like this? (I know it's not very efficient but it's only a small table.

```
Country District Salescount CountryTotal
----------------------------------------
France   A       10         75
France   B       20         75
France   C       45         75
Germany  A       30         85
Germany  B       5          85
Germany  C       50         85
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a inner join with the total

```
  select 
  a.Country, 
  if(upper(a.District) like 'A%', 'A',
  if(upper(a.District) like '%B', 'B','C')) as Field1Type,
  count(a.*) as Salescount,
  t.CountryTotal
  FROM tablename as a 
  INNER JOIN (
      Select 
      Country, 
      count(*)  CountryTotal
      FROM tablename
      group by Country

  )  on a.Country = t.country
  group by a.Country, a.District;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing the query like this:

```
select t.Country, 
       (case when upper(t.District) like 'A%' then 'A',
             when upper(t.District) like '%B' then 'B',
             else 'C'
        end) as Field1Type,
       count(*) as Salescount,
       t2.CountryCount
FROM tablename t join
     (select t2.country, count(*) as CountryCount
      from tablename t2
      group by t2.country
     ) t2
     on t.country = t2.country
group by t.Country, t.District;
```

The use of `case` is better than nested `if`s for two reasons.  First `case` is standard SQL.  Second, there is no reason to nest the functionality.

By the way, most other databases support window functions which makes this much easier to express.